# Javascript - Agregar botón RESTAR número a un contador de clicks

Tags: javascript

Tengo un contador de clicks (en prácticas) que funciona muy bien, pero me gustaría completarlo **con una función de restar los clicks** cada vez que se hace 1 click en el:

**div class="restar"** .

Alguna idea...?

Muchas gracias.

```
<div id="clicks">0</div>
<div class="sumar" onClick="clickME();">Sumar</div>

<div class="restar">Restar</div>
```

---

```
var clicks=0;
function clickME() {
clicks += 1;document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Acabo de agregar otro div (en un modal) que también muestra el resultado de la suma (**en el div clicksdos**) y me hice un lío tremendo. La solución de restar sólo funciona en el div "clicks", pero no en clickdos.

Y es evidente que algo estoy haciendo mal...

```
<div id="clicks">0</div>
<div id="clicksdos">0</div>

<div class="sumar" onClick="clickME();clickME2();">Sumar</div>

<div class="restar" onClick="restar();restardos();">Restar</div>
```

---

```
var clicks=0;function clickME(){clicks += 1;document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks};

function restar() {
if (clicks>0) clicks -= 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
}

var clicksdos=0;function clickME2(){clicksdos += 1;document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;

function restardos() {
if (clicksdos>0) clicksdos -= 1;
document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Pablo te propongo 3 soluciones:

1) dejar fija el id (te tocaría hacer lo mismo por cada elemento)

```js
let total_element = document.getElementById('total'); // obtenemos el elemento

function sumar () {
  let total_value = parseInt(total_element.innerHTML);
  total_element.innerHTML = total_value + 1;
}


function restar () {
  let total_value = parseInt(total_element.innerHTML);
  if (total_value == 0) return; // validamos que el valor no sea menor a 0
  total_element.innerHTML = total_value - 1;
}

// asignamos funcion click a cada Div
document.getElementById('sumar').addEventListener('click', sumar);

document.getElementById('restar').addEventListener('click', restar);
```

```html
<div id="sumar">Sumar</div>
<div id="restar">Restar</div>
<div id="total">0</div>
```

2) Definir los ids a iterar

```js
let ids = ['resultado1', 'resultado2']; // ids a iterar
let total_base = 0;

function sumar() {
  total_base++;
  set_total(total_base)
}


function restar() {
  if (total_base == 0) return;
  total_base--;
  set_total(total_base)
}

function set_total(value) {
  ids.forEach(function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
  });
}
// asignamos funcion click a cada Div
document.getElementById('sumar').addEventListener('click', sumar);

document.getElementById('restar').addEventListener('click', restar);
```

```html
<div id='sumar'>Sumar</div>
<div id='restar'>Restar</div>
<div id='resultado1'>0</div>
<div id='resultado2'>0</div>
```

3) Obtener todos los elementos de una misma clase, iterarlos y asignarles el valor de la respuesta.

```js
let total_base = 0;

function sumar() {
  total_base++;
  set_total(total_base)
}


function restar() {
  if (total_base == 0) return;
  total_base--;
  set_total(total_base)
}

function set_total(value) {
  //recorremos cada elemento que tenga clase total y le asignamos el valor
  document.querySelectorAll('.total').forEach(function(element) {
    element.innerHTML = value
  })
}

// asignamos funcion click a cada Div
document.getElementById('sumar').addEventListener('click', sumar);

document.getElementById('restar').addEventListener('click', restar);
```

```html
<div id='sumar'>Suma</div>
<div id='restar'>Resta</div>
<div class='total'>0</div>
<div class='total'>0</div>
<div class='total'>0</div>
<div class='total'>0</div>
<div class='total'>0</div>
<div class='total'>0</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Las tres propuestas funcionan de maravilla y se ajustan mucho a lo que estoy buscando. Impecable!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="clicks">0</div>
<div class="sumar" onClick="clickME()";>Sumar</div>
<div class="restar" onClick="clickME2();">Restar</div>
```

---

```
var clicks=0;
function clickME() {
clicks += 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
}
function clickME2() {
if (clicks>0) clicks -= 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
}
```

Comment: Está muy bien, muchas gracias. El problema es que luego de "0" el contador se pone en valores negativos (-0 ... -1 .... -2...) y pienso que deberia quedarse en "0".

Comment: Acabo de editarlo para que eso ya no ocurra. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Juan. Ahora funciona. Agregué algo al código original, y tu solución es perfecta (muchas gracias), pero no me resta los valores de mi nuevo script, el primer post EDITADO ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal...? Gracias...

Comment: @Juan_m_2 gracias por tu respuesta pero te sugiero agregar información acerca del código, que es lo que realiza y como ayudaría al OP a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Espero te funcione, cuando llega a 0 ya no resta. :)

```js
var inicio = 0; //se inicializa una variable en 0

function aumentar(){ // se crean la funcion y se agrega al evento onclick en en la etiqueta button con id aumentar

var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').innerHTML = ++inicio; //se obtiene el valor del input, y se incrementa en 1 el valor que tenga.
}

var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad');

function disminuir(){ // se crean la funcion y se agrega al evento onclick en en la etiqueta button con id disminuir

if(cantidad.innerHTML === '0'){
console.log('no hace nada');

}else{

cantidad.innerHTML = --inicio;

}
   
}
```

```html
<div id='aumentar' onclick="aumentar()">sumar</div>
<div id='disminuir' onclick="disminuir()">restar</div>

<div id="cantidad" >0</div>
```