# Javascript - No puedo borrar el div

Tags: javascript

Luego de seguir mejorando el script ( **[aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253903/javascript-agregar-bot%C3%B3n-restar-n%C3%BAmero-a-un-contador-de-clicks)** ) y de haber agregado la función:

**this.parentElement.style.display='none';**

para borrar el div padre (incluyendo el div restar) se me presentó un problema:

```
<div id="padre">
<div class="restar" onClick="restar();restardos();this.parentElement.style.display='none';">Restar</div>
</div>
```

Y es que veo que no me sirve el **style.display="none"**, para lo que finalmente quiero, por cuanto he probado con empty() y con remove(), pero tampoco me funciona.

```
<div id="padre">
<div class="restar" onclick="restar();restardos();empty()">Restar</div>
</div>

<!-- ----- -->

<div id="padre">
<div class="restar" onclick="restar();restardos();remove()">Restar</div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo quitar el div padre al hacer click en "restar" y sin usar **this.parentElement.style.display='none';**...?

He probado con ésto, pero tampoco funciona, y tampoco me gusta porque si tengo muchos "padres" diferentes (demasiados IDs) el escript es interminable...

```
<div id="padre">
<div class="restar" onClick="restar();restardos();">Restar</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".restar").click(function(event) {
      $("#padre").remove();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendaría que evites el uso de funciones *in line*, como ocurre aquí:

```
onclick="restar();restardos();this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"
```

El problema es que haciendo esto creas un documento dependiente, y si es un proyecto grande el mantenimiento se hace complicado, porque si hay que cambiar funciones o parámetros tienes que ir a buscar en el HTML cada elemento para modificarlo.

Es recomendable usar la escucha de eventos de Javascript, de ese modo los elementos se escuchan por su id, o por el id del padre en este caso, luego hay formas de determinar si se hizo click en el hijo específicamente. En este ejemplo nos valdremos de que el hijo no tiene `id` para determinarlo. Si tuviese `id` escuchamos directamente a ese elemento por su id y listo.

Cabe decir que la escucha de eventos es un concepto mucho más amplio, y que se pueden escuchar diferentes acciones en los elementos: click, cambio, teclas presionadas, etc. Y que en la escucha los elementos se pueden identificar por id, clases, tipos, etc.<sup>1</sup>

Aplicando también algo más relativo a las *buenas prácticas*, he agregado una escucha a `DOMContentLoaded`, siempre conviene ponerlo, para asegurarnos de que el código Javascript no se lanzará antes de que el DOM esté listo, pudiendo provocar errores o funcionamiento inadecuado en el código. En ese bloque debes poner todos los *listeners*  de los elementos del DOM, como he hecho aquí: `divPadre.addEventListener('click', childClick, false);` Las funciones como `childClick`, `restar`, etc. irían fuera de ese bloque.

Otra cosa que conviene saber es que una misma función se puede asignar a más de un elemento.

```js
/* Conviene siempre usar esta función para que nada se ejecute antes de cargarse el DOM*/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var divPadre = document.getElementById("padre");
  divPadre.addEventListener('click', childClick, false);

});

function restar() {
  console.log("Restar");
}

function restardos() {
  console.log("Restar 2");
}

function childClick(e) {
  /*Referencia al div clickeado*/
  var thisDiv = e.target;
  /*Modo de comprobación que se clickeó el div hijo (no tiene id)*/
  if (thisDiv.id == "") {
    restar();
    restardos();
    thisDiv.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(thisDiv.parentNode);
    /*Si fuera sólo ocultarlo, sin removerlo del DOM*/
    //thisDiv.parentNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">Lorem ipsum
  <div class="restar">X</div>
</div>
```

---

1. Para más detalles leer el apartado [*¿Porqué utilizar addEventListener?*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), en MDN.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! Lo tendré en cuenta para ir practicando y aprendiendo. Son mis primeros pasos en JS. Muy amable de tu parte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo a mi mismo, porque la solución era simple:

**onclick="restar();restardos();this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"**

```
<div id="padre">
<div class="restar" onclick="restar();restardos();this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">X</div>
</div>
```